# Inline data formatting in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting

Within a rails app I have a .jst.eco template which includes the line...

```
<span> <%= @event.get 'create_at' %> </span>
```

...which renders the date like so 2015-01-17 11:04:03.

However I only want to display 2015-01-17. Is there a neat formatting trick I can use within the <%= ... %>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the object you have. If it is a time object, you can do:

```
@event.get('create_at').strftime('%F')
```

if it is just a string, then first you should parse it:

```
Time.parse(@event.get('create_at')).strftime('%F')
```

According to [`.strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) docs `%F` is `The ISO 8601 date format (%Y-%m-%d)`

Comment: Best answer because of the string comment. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can write as:

```
span> <%= @event.get('create_at').to_s(:db) %> </span>
# or
span> <%= @event.get('create_at').to_formatted_s(:db) %> </span>
```

`:db` means `'%Y-%m-%d`. Check out [DATE_FORMATS](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#DATE_FORMATS).